# LinearLayout child weight not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I'm trying to build the screen from picture on a tablet. 
Inside fragment i have a **[RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html)** with items. Each item has as root a **[LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html)**. and has exactly **8 children spread horizontally with weight 1** (as in below code). The first cell on each row is a **[TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)** and the other cells are a **CustomView** (a vertical [LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) with 2 [TextViews](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)).

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
   android:orientation="horizontal" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/item_id"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
       android:layout_margin="2dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:background="@drawable/item_border"
       android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_id"
       android:fontFamily="@font/cabin_bold"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:padding="5dp"
       android:text="@string/mock"
       android:textColor="@android:color/black"
       android:textSize="17sp" />

   <CustomView   X 7 times
       android:id="@+id/item_attr1"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_margin="2dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       app:titleText="Mock" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Given that, the row's children are not spread correctly on width, as you can see in the image. I've tried with `weightSum` attribute to row's root [LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html), but no luck. I've noticed that this issue appears (especially) when the first child of the row (which is a [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)) has a many characters.

[image]

Here is fragment's layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F1F1F1">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:fabSize="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loading_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
        android:text="@string/loading"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any ideas are appreciated

Comment: try to add `android:weightSum="8"` in outer layout .

Comment: you need to have same weight of all textViews, and same weight of all custormViews. check it with all textview's weight = 3, and all customView's weight = 1

Comment: @ADM i've already tried android:weightSum="8", no difference

Comment: Can you post the layout with ALL parameters?

Comment: @Kelevandos i've updated the code. The CustomView is multiplicated for 7 times in total (except id for each one, ofc).

Comment: Can you try removing the android:background and android:drawableTop attributes? Let me know if this changes anything

Comment: @Kelevandos, tried this right now, no difference

Comment: Alright, so next try - can you post the xml of your recyclerView? Are you using a custom LayoutManager, or just LinearLayoutManager?

Comment: @Kelevandos, added xml of my recyclerView. Its a classic LinearLayoutManager

Answer (score 1):

On the TextView:

```
<TextView 
    ...
    android:maxLines="1" 
    android:maxLength="8" 
    android:ellipsize="end"/>
```

This will prevent the TextViews from becoming too big. You can play about with the `maxLength` attribute to see which will fit your scenario better.

Comment: This is not fit in my case, I need that textView to spread in height as long is its text

Comment: Okay, sorry to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

Your LinearLayout should encompass the rest of the code it's self closing now. Replace the closing tag /> with >

Close the LinearLayout below the custom view

Comment: Yeah, I only forgot to add closing tag in this code, but of course, it exists in local xml.